# Scaling an image proportionally based on the image's dimensions and my restriction size

Tags: image, geometry

Looking for an expression that allows me to accomplish this:

I have an image of arbitrary width/height, whose dimensions I can grab before I draw it.
Because the image may be very large, I want to scale it down.

My canvas is going to have width w and height h.
For illustration purposes let's just say it's 320x240.

If the dimensions of the image are equal or smaller than the dimensions of the canvas, then the scale ratio is just 1.
If they are larger, I will scale it proportional to how much larger it is compared to the canvas size.

So for example if my image is 640x480, my scale ratio will be 0.5
If my image is 640x240, my scale ratio would still be 0.5
Similarly if it were 320x480

Can this be written in a single math expression? For ex:

```
def scale_ratio(canvas_width, canvas_height, image_width, image_height)
   #math formula for calculating scale
   return scale
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function scale(canvas_width, canvas_height, image_width, image_height) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(canvas_width / image_width, canvas_height / image_height), 1);
}
```

EDIT: You might want to do something like this to reduce rounding errors:

```
var scale_width = image_width;
var scale_height = image_height;
if (image_width > canvas_width || image_height > canvas_height) {
    var image_ratio = image_height / image_width;
    if (image_ratio * canvas_width > canvas_height) {
        scale_width = canvas_height / image_ratio;
        scale_height = canvas_height;
    } else {
        scale_width = canvas_width;
        scale_height = image_ratio * canvas_width;
    }
}
```